# Render haskell list data to web page

Tags: haskell, pretty-print, haskell-snap-framework

I'm using snap framework and haskell to create simple web application.I want to know How can I render a list to web page,It is like this I have a list with first name and last name

```
[["firstName1","lastName1"],["firstName2","lastName2"],["firstName3","lastName3"]]
```

I want to display these information in two columns,What are the possible ways to do this,I was able to bind single value information and display on webpage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don's suggestion of blaze-html is one way to do it, but I find that when I do it that way I have more of a tendency to violate the commonly used MVC design pattern by embedding the view (in this case the HTML) into your Haskell code.  In some cases if you're just trying to do something quick and dirty this may be the thing to do.  But if you want this to fit into a larger application in a way that separates the view from the controller and allows designers to work with it who are unfamiliar with Haskell, then you might be better off using the Heist template system.

We have a Heist tutorial [here](http://snapframework.com/docs/tutorials/heist).  I also recently wrote a series of [blog posts](http://softwaresimply.blogspot.com/) about just this sort of thing.  The [second post in the series](http://softwaresimply.blogspot.com/2011/04/views-controllers-and-heist.html) in particular is probably the most relevant to your question.  Here's some code that does something like what you want:

```
names :: [(Text,Text)]
names = [("Alice", "Anderson"), ("Bob", "Brown")]

nameSplice :: (Text, Text) -> Splice Application
nameSplice name =
    runChildrenWithText [("firstName", fst name), ("lastName", snd name)]

namesSplice :: Splice Application
namesSplice = mapSplices nameSplice names
```

After you bind the names splice somewhere in your application with `bindSplice "names" namesSplice` you can get at this data from a template like this:

```
<table>
<names>
  <tr><td><firstName/></td><td><lastName/></td></tr>
</names>
</table>
```

The nice thing about this is that the web designer has complete control over how the names are displayed.  If they needed to change the display to say an unordered list in the format "lastname, firstname" that would be very easy to do here without needing to recompile your application.

Comment: I wouldn't say that blaze-html violates MVC as long as you keep the html-generation part separate from the IO/logic part, for example by having them in separate modules. In either case, there's going to have to be some kind of interface or convention between the controller and the view, and there are benefits to having this interface be automatically verifiable by a compiler.

Comment: @hammar Good point.  It is possible to preserve MVC and still use the blaze approach.  Although in my experience the run-time/compile-time separation that heist gives you does tend to make view/controller separation easier.

Answer (score 4):

I have a strong preference for [blaze-html](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-html), as an excellent set of combinators for quickly translating structured Haskell data types into html.

It has a nice [home with lots of examples](http://jaspervdj.be/blaze/), like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Prelude hiding (head)
import Control.Monad
import Text.Blaze.Html4.Strict
import Text.Blaze.Renderer.Text
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as T

main = T.writeFile "f" (renderHtml (draw xs))
  where
    xs = [("firstName1","lastName1"),("firstName2","lastName2"),("firstName3","lastName3")]

draw xs = html $ do
    head $ title "Example"
    body $ do
        h1 "Heading"
        table $ forM_ xs $ \(f,l) ->
            tr $ do
                td f
                td f
```

Generates a `text` string containing this table:

```
Heading

firstName1  firstName1
firstName2  firstName2
firstName3  firstName3
```

If you can output `text` from snap, you should be good.

Comment: Hi Thanxx for the your quick reply,Currently I'm using with snap,can I integrate this with snap?

Comment: @123Ex http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap-core/0.4.1/doc/html/Snap-Types.html#v:writeText is a convenience function for helping you output Text in Snap.

Comment: Thanxx Carl,I tried above way but that gives regarding type mismatching,As I noticed If we take "title" it type definition says "title :: Html -> Html",so we are passing String value here,I'm I misunderstood something??

Comment: @123Ex make sure you have the overloadedstrings pragma at the beginning of the file

Comment: thanxxx,That should be the case!